# Stop the loud beeping?

Tags: windows-xp, sound-card

Every time my computer freezes, if I click or scroll or otherwise interact, it beeps so loudly  my ears actually hurt. If I have earbuds plugged in, it'll beep so loudly that people two rooms over will ask what the beeping noise was.

How can I disable this feature/bug? My ears just can't take the abuse!

It's ringing the pc speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the system "beep" noise by going into the Device Manager, unhiding hidden devices, finding the "Beep" and then disabling it.

HowToGeek has a nice guide on how to do it:  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/turn-off-the-annoying-windows-xp-system-beeps/

Comment: No beep device located: http://i.imgur.com/bhs0Z.png

Comment: @Cyclone expand the "Non plug and play devices" part of the tree, it should be in there.

Comment: Command line version: `sc stop beep & sc config beep start= demand`